# Microsoft outlook graph events api: how to get different timezone?

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to GET Microsoft calendar events. Default timezone of my outlook account is US Eastern Time Zone. But the response I'm getting from rest api call is all in UTC. How can I get my default time zone i.e. US Eastern Time?

Here is my code:

```
def make_api_call(method, url, token, payload = None, parameters = None):
  headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'python_tutorial/1.0',
              'Authorization' : 'Bearer {0}'.format(token),
              'Accept' : 'application/json'}

  request_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
  instrumentation = { 'client-request-id' : request_id,
                      'return-client-request-id' : 'true' }

  headers.update(instrumentation)

  response = None

  if (method.upper() == 'GET'):
      response = requests.get(url, headers = headers, params = parameters)
  elif (method.upper() == 'POST'):
      headers.update({ 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' })
      response = requests.post(url, headers = headers, data = json.dumps(payload), params = parameters)

  return response

def get_my_events(access_token, start_date_time, end_date_time):
    get_events_url = graph_endpoint.format('/me/calendarView')
    query_parameters = {'$top': '10',
    '$select': 'subject,start,end,location',
    '$orderby': 'start/dateTime ASC',
    'startDateTime': start_date_time,
    'endDateTime': end_date_time}

    r = make_api_call('GET', get_events_url, access_token, parameters = query_parameters)
    if (r.status_code == requests.codes.ok):
        return r.json()
    else:
        return "{0}: {1}".format(r.status_code, r.text)
```

**UPDATE:**

Anyone else coming here for this kind of question, you need to update the headers to send any specific time zone. Here are the update headers, make sure you surround timezone in double quotes:

```
  headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'python_tutorial/1.0',
              'Authorization' : 'Bearer {0}'.format(token),
              'Accept' : 'application/json',
              'Prefer': 'outlook.timezone="Eastern Standard Time"'}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the outlook api, but what is stopping you from using datetime.timedelta to make the conversion yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the time zone using the `Prefer: outlook.timezone` header.

From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendarview):

> Prefer: outlook.timezone
>
> Use this to specify the time zone for start and end times in the response. If not specified, those time values are returned in UTC.

For example, to set it to US Eastern you would send

```
Prefer: outlook.timezone="Eastern Standard Time"
```

Comment: Thanks Marc. Headers is a dict, any idea how would I specify that in the headers dict?

Comment: I got it Marc and have edited my question for anyone else coming here for this kind of question. Thanks for your help